# Ionic React/Framer Motion is slow on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, frame-rate, framer-motion

My Ionic React app works well on PC but becomes laggy on mobile, `not sure but I think it's the framer motion library that is causing this framing problem`.
I have been looking for a solution to this problem but could not find the answer.

> This this the link to the site [https://trayfoods.pages.dev](https://trayfoods.com)

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.to/nilanth/how-to-reduce-react-app-loading-time-by-70-1kmm
https://proxify.io/articles/build-large-scale-React-apps#6-obey-naming-conventions

Since my 2 previous answers you have tried already , maybe then try to reduce the react app loading time by lazy loading the pages themselves and components

Note:
makesure your App.js to  App.jsx or it wont work

```
//For instance
const Dashboard = lazy(() => import('components/Dashboard'));
```

How i applied it

```
import { lazy } from "react";
//inside my components/i have an index.js file 
export const NavbarLazy = lazy(()=> import('../components/Navbar/Navbar'));

//inside App.jsx 
import {NavbarLazy } from './components/index';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavbarLazy />
    </div>
  );
}
```